# Send and receive Fax

Tags: c#, fax

I need to develop a service which can send and receive fax. I have to put the received faxes into a database. On the other side, I have to look into the database, if there are faxes to send and when yes, send it. Now, can someone give me a tip, how I can do this - particularly the part for receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up "fax server software".
Most new modems are able to send and receive faxes which use different encoding than computer terminal data.  Hylafax is free, runs on Linux and may provide all of what you need.  Have a look:

http://www.hylafax.org/content/Main_Page

Comment: I personally found ICTFAX a far better project than hylafax as it is FOIp solution while hylafax is not a foip solution amd based on old iax modem technology

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive faxes, you will firstly need fax numbers to send to. These numbers must be routed from the telecoms provider over an SS7, ISDN or E1 line to some fax gateway equipment (eg. AudioCodes media gateway.) Then you will need some fax terminating software like Asterisk or the like on a server which can terminate the fax as a file. Asterisk can write Call Data Records directly to a database. I would not put the actual fax files in a database.

To send faxes, you can use Asterisk control files. You will also need a telecoms line to send this out over, or possibly a SIP peer that can send the faxes for you. There are also companies like [Monopond](http://monopond.com) that has an API for sending faxes.

There are other things to consider, ie. whether you are going to use G11 protocol or T38 etc.